# f select multiple select is not working using in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have working on project using ruby on rails. I have created a form with many fields and one field is for jobs where I want to choose more then one job but now I am not able to choose more then one job with following code. Working with ruby on rails 3 and HAML. I also mention `multiple true` but still its not working.

```
= f.select :jobs, options_from_collection_for_select(Demojob.all, 'name','name' ), :multiple => true
```

Comment: 'not working' means what you are getting on your approach ?

Comment: I'm getting single value dropdown list for choosing not multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the implementation of the form builder select method ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L830)), you'll see that the method signature is:

```
select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

`multiple` flag should be passed using `html_options` hash, not `options`. In your case, it should be:

```
f.select :jobs, options_from_collection_for_select(Demojob.all, 'name', 'name'), {}, :multiple => true
```

Or, even better, if you prefer new hash syntax:

```
f.select :jobs, options_from_collection_for_select(Demojob.all, 'name', 'name'), {}, multiple: true
```

Lastly, there's no need to use `options_from_collection_for_select` with form builder, you can simply pass the options as arrays:

```
f.select :jobs, Demojob.all.collect { |job| [job.name, job.name] }, {}, multiple: true
```

Cheers!

Comment: @VarinderSohal: Glad I could help. ;)